# How to render data from json into a div class

Tags: jquery, json

My JSON Data looks like that:

```html
[
{
 "Name": "Fitbit"
 "Category":"App"
}

]
```

And I want to display the data over an image in a div row:

```html
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <a href="http://www.amazon.de/Fitbit/b/ref=bl_dp_s_web_1703705031?ie=UTF8&node=1703705031&field-lbr_brands_browse-bin=Fitbit">
             <img src="/img/apps/fitbit.png" class="thumbnail img-responsive">

        </a>
    </div>
```

What is the best practise for that? jQuery ajax?

Comment: please be more specific, title say one thing and description another... how would you display this data? you want to add a class to a div with some field of this json data (which one)? or you just want to print out some text over an image? (and how it is supposed to be formatted? json style or what else?)

Comment: sorry. the data should be display in text over the image. Basically i want to understand how i do get the data (in my case the name and the category) and display it as text on the image

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I fully understand your question but Ill try.

You send the request for the data (ajax is fine) and once you get the json data you can dynamically create the div populate it with the json data then append it to the page and your css can position it over the picture. Check out

```
Document.createElement();
```

here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement

Answer (score 0):

Well, first create a container where to put the text in

HTML

```
<a href="#">
   <img src="http://media.digitalcameraworld.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/123/2012/05/Landscape_photography_tips.foamy_3.jpg" class="thumbnail img-responsive">
   <div id="textImage"></div>
</a>
```

give some style to place it over the image

CSS

```
#textImage{
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 20px;
}
```

then, in jQuery, loop through the object data and concatenate a string variable, like this

```
$.each(data, function(){
   for (var property in this) {
    text += property + ": "+ this[property]+"; ";
  }
})
```

in this case the output would be `Name: Fitbit; Category: App;`, but you can compose your string in the way you prefer

So, now just append your string in the div container, and that's it

```
$('#textImage').text(text);
```

See the working example here: [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/w9zyjte1/)